# Springboot JPA (Hibernate) not getting table and column by name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

When I am defining my model as -

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User{

    @Id
    @NotNull
    private String employeeId;

}
```

I am getting this error -

`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column user0_.employeeid does not exist`

but when I am using this -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`User`")
public class User{

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "`employeeId`")
    private String employeeId;

}
```

In my application.yml -

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
        implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
      ddl-auto: update
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  datasource:
    url: ${db.host}
    username: ${db.user}
    password: ${db.password}
```

Why I am getting error in first one ? I don't want to specifically tell the names, spring boot jpa should automatically find the table and column by naming.

**My tables and columns are same as my naming of entity and column, I don't want to change in the name, that's why I am using `PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`**

What's wrong with 1st one ?

Comment: Do you use `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers` property ?

Comment: @SternK no I haven't use it

Comment: @SternK as you can see it is finding `user0_.employeeid` but it should be `user0_.employeeId` it is coveting it two lowecase

Comment: @SternK I tried it with `true` and now its working !! Thank you ! You can post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you should avoid to use [upper case table or column names](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names). But if you do not want to change it you can tell hibernate to use [global quoting](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-global-quoted-identifiers):

```xml
<property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all ,you are using the legacy naming strategy instead of the default provided by Spring boot. Hibernate maps field names using a physical strategy and an implicit strategy. Hibernate uses the Physical Naming Strategy to map our logical names to a SQL table and its columns. Spring Boot, provides defaults for both these strategies `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy` defaults to `org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy`, and `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy` defaults to `org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy`

The default naming strategy for spring-boot will :

- Replace dots with underscores
- Change camel case to snake case
- Lower-case table name

So if your database follows these conventions while you created the tables and columns then you could remove the hibernate naming stratergy keys from `application.properties` and spring will automatically pick up the tables by resolving it from the name itself.

Comment: no my tables and columns are same as my naming of entity and column, I don't want to change in the name, that's why I am using `PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`

Comment: @PankajSharma If that is the case then please share entire stacktrace with hibernate logs enabled for more analysis.